# can't started my app. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []

Tags: mysql, docker, hibernate, docker-compose, tomcat9

Please help me with my error. My application not started. I can't understand where I could breake my app.

```
INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1432)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1057)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:123)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:90)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property>-->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">name</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:9.0

COPY ./target/ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: mysql
      DATABASE_USER: user
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: password
      DATABASE_NAME: my_db
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./src/main/resources/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

Stacktrace:

```
08-Dec-2022 14:31:01.535 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.35] using APR version [1.7.0].
08-Dec-2022 14:31:01.536 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
08-Dec-2022 14:31:01.537 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
08-Dec-2022 14:31:01.808 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020]
08-Dec-2022 14:31:03.059 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2022 14:31:03.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2907] milliseconds
08-Dec-2022 14:31:03.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
08-Dec-2022 14:31:03.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
08-Dec-2022 14:31:03.508 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war]
08-Dec-2022 14:31:07.191 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Dec-2022 14:31:10.629 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
08-Dec-2022 14:31:10.634 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
08-Dec-2022 14:31:10.641 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
08-Dec-2022 14:31:10.643 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@17.0.4.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.4.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:91)
 java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
 java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.4.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
08-Dec-2022 14:31:10.653 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [7,143] ms
08-Dec-2022 14:31:10.656 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2022 14:31:10.669 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [7269] milliseconds
08-Dec-2022 14:31:14.969 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1432)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1057)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:123)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:90)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, managed to fix it by changing the shutdown port.

The issue was resolved by changing the configuration in server.xml (to be found under the tomcat/config folder):

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

to

```
<Server port="8004" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

In your case it might be a different port.